# Dungeons Example In-app billing example stops unexpectedly

Tags: in-app-billing

I have followed the steps to do the Dungeons Example In-app billing tutorial. I've been able to upload the apk to my dev console and to my phone (HTC Incredible 2, ver. 2.3.4 with Google Play Store ver. 3.5.16). Once I touch-select the app on my phone, a toast message pops up saying "Restoring transactions", then I get the error message that it stopped unexpectedly. I have also tried the "Simple In-App Billing Payment" tutorial at http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/, and I get the same error message (although, no screen or toast pops up, just the error message).

Notes:

-my test account is the account for my phone, and not my dev account email.

-not quite certain as to how to get the logcat messages for debugging from my phone.

-at the dev console page, the apps do not say "draft" but are unpublished, activated, and have all necessary fields filled.

Additional information:

-My goal is just to have a simple donation app, where patrons may donate $1 or $2 if they so wish, that's all. This in-app bill is not attached to the primary app that is for free.

I'm sure I'm missing some simple step/information/etc.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Troog